# how to create three random numbers in javascript and then tell input is odd or not?

Tags: javascript

how to create three random numbers in javascript and then tell input is odd or not?

Comment: what is the problem with your code  `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));`

Comment: You need to make a couple of  `if else` statements, Try making those yourself and post what you achieve here so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if odd:

```
num % 2;
```

That will return 0 or 1. If you want it to return true or false, then do

```
(num % 2) == 1;
```

Make a "isOdd" function and you can use it to check your random numbers against:

```
function isOdd(num) {
    return (num % 2) == 1;
}
```

Use it like

```
function randomizer() {
    var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    var c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    if (isOdd(a)) {
    \\Give more points because it's odd
    }
}
```

Here's a very simple working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqLVxM

Answer (score 0):

to verify that all numbers are even use this function

```
function areEven(a,b,c){
 return a%2==0 && b%2==0 && c%2==0 
}
```

to verify that all numbers are odd use this function

```
function areOdd(a,b,c){
 return a%2!=0 && b%2!=0 && c%2!=0 
}
```

to verify that all numbers are are in sequence use this function :

```
 function areInSequence(a,b,c){
  var array = [a,b,c];
  array.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  var validity=false;
  var i;
  var length = array.length
  for (i =0; i < length-1 ; i++) {
      if((array [i+1] - array [i]) == 1){
        validity=true;
      }else validity=false;
  }
  return validity;
}
```

combine this functions in your code and if you need help leave a comment thanks!